# Sleep command in launch file?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Is there any way to make a launch file sleep between executing different nodes and launch files?
Also is there any way to write some logs from launch file ?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36061/sleep-command-in-launch-file?/) by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 717 on 2012-06-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2012-06-08**:
Can you give more information about what you're doing that you need the sleep for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- Launch files intentionally make no guarantees about the timing or order in which various nodes start running. It is a basic ROS concept that each node should start and run independently, while others may come and go.
- Many kinds of logging are available, via launch files and other mechanisms. What are you looking for?

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3